# What is my error with finding the tangential force on a pendulum?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces

I know that it is commonly known that the tangential force due to gravity on a simple pendulum is $mg\sin(\theta)$. However, I can draw a picture where it appears to, simultaneously, be $\frac{mg}{\sin(\theta)}$. Obviously I know this must be wrong since it is commonly known that the correct force is $mg\sin(\theta)$, and obviously there must be something wrong with my drawing, but I can't find where the error is. This is each drawing:
[image: Drawings of pendulum forces.]

Comment: Please be aware that, in general, check-my-work and find-my-error questions are off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The force vector itself must be the hypotenuse of the triangle, because $a$ is a *component* of the vector in the direction perpendicular to the rope. Therefore, OP's second picture is incorrect.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was checking my angles for an error and didn't consider the fallacy of the component vector taking a longer side than the force vector. Thank you!